# Set NSArray value when array is contained in an NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I want to SET items in an array in a dictionary.
I have an NSDictionary below, an instance called"currentCityNode".  In that Dictionary is an array item (amongst other things).  The array item is called "TheConnections"
The code below successfully reads the array.

```
 NSArray *theConnectionsArray = [currentCityNode objectForKey:@"TheConnections"];
 (theConnectionsArray now contains the previously loaded values '3','7', and '9')
```

Now I want to set ONE of the values in this array.  Make the second value '7' a '5'.

I have tried a few variations, not able to get it yet.

```
[currentCityNode addObject:notsurewhattoputhere forKey:@"TheConnections"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array and dictionary must be mutable and something like this should work. If theConnectionsArray is already mutable then you wont have to use `mutableCopy`.

```
NSMutableArray *theConnectionsArray = [[currentCityNode objectForKey:@"TheConnections"] mutableCopy];
[theConnectionsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"5"];
[currentCityNode setObject:theConnectionsArray forKey:@"TheConnections"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the array you're retrieving is mutable (an instance of `NSMutableArray`):

```
[[currentCityNode objectForKey:@"TheConnections"] addObject:@"objectToAdd"];
```

If the array is just an `NSArray`:

```
NSArray *array = [currentCityNode objectForKey:@"TheConnections"];
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [array mutableCopy];
[mutableArray addObject:@"objectToAdd"];
[currentCityNode setObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray] forKey:@"TheConnections"];
[mutableArray release];
```

Essentially if the array is immutable (and thus can't be added to easily) you need to create a mutable copy and assign that copy back to "TheConnections".